# erlang os:cmd() command with UTF8 binary

Tags: unicode, encoding, erlang, utf

I'm trying to get an Erlang function to execute a bash command containing unicode characters. For example, I want to execute the equivalent of:

```
touch /home/jani/ჟანიweł
```

I put that command in variable `D`, for example:

```
io:fwrite("~ts", [list_to_binary(D)]).                                                                       
touch /home/jani/ჟანიwełok
```

but after I execute:

```
os:cmd(D)
```

I get file called `á??á??á??á??weÅ?`. How can I fix it?

```
os:cmd(binary_to_list(unicode:characters_to_binary("touch /home/jani/编程"))).
```

Executing this command creates a file named `ç¼?ç¨?`, while executing the equivalent `touch` command directly in a terminal creates the file with the correct name.

Comment: tried using 
os:cmd(unicode:characters_to_list(D, latin1))

os:cmd(unicode:characters_to_list(D, unicode))

they didn't help

Comment: Instead of calling out to `touch`, why not use the Erlang `file` module to create or update the file in question? For example you can use one of the `file:write_file_info/2,3` functions to update the file access and modification times like `touch` does. See http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#write_file_info-2 for details.

Comment: I want to pass unicode string as parameter to some other bash script actually, I wrote about touch command just to simplify question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because Erlang reads your source files like latin1 by default, but on newer versions of erlang you can set your files to use unicode.

```
%% coding: utf-8

-module(test).
-compile(export_all).

test() ->
    COMMAND = "touch ჟანიweł",
    os:cmd(COMMAND).
```

and then compiling and executing the module works fine

```
rorra-air:~ > erl
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V6.4  (abort with ^G)
1> c(test).
{ok,test}
2> test:test().
[]
```

and it created the file on my filesystem

```
rorra-air:~ > ls -lta
total 144
-rw-r--r--   1 rorra  staff      0 Jun  9 15:18 ჟანიweł
```